# Addition of Vectors if their tails don't coincide

Tags: vectors

To add two vectors do their tails have to coincide ?  What if their tails don't coincide as shown in the diagram below ?[image]

Comment: Your length marked *No!* is $(\mathbf{r}_2+\mathbf{v}_2) -(\mathbf{r}_1+\mathbf{v}_1)$

Comment: We can't add r and v vectors since r is a radius vector and v is a velocity vector

Answer (score 2):

For addition, we can move (free) vectors such that tails coincide and apply the ordinary rules.

In that case we have that

$$\vec v_1+\Delta \vec v=\vec v_2 \implies \Delta \vec v=\vec v_2-\vec v_1$$

Comment: @Arthur You are right! I add that.Thanks